# Error in Appkernel Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I keep getting the same error...I've tried of using everyone solution with no luck 
**Error :     ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 17:
Attempted to load class "AppBundle" from namespace "AppBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?**

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new OC\PlatformBundle\OCPlatformBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could please share you AppBundle class as well? Also your directory structure around it!

Comment: thanks a lot my problem is resolved :)

Comment: Good to know, could you please share your solution or choose the right one below? This is important to help other people and solve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have the directory `AppBundle` , if it does not exist remove this line from `AppKernel.ph` file :

```
new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
```

Comment: it's thanks to you that everything is fine now thank you very much :)

Comment: Accept the answer if I answered yo question please :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your AppBundle class is not (or badly) defined. You should have this in `src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```